# target image folder on mobile (Android or IOS) when html input[type="file"] is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, input

i have this problem and can't figure out:

i have a simple input

```
<input type="file" id="mfile" name="file" class="input display-none optional_check" accept="image/jpg"/>
```

It works perfectly on desktop browsers but when i click it from a mobile device it opens a choiche between:

1. File system or Document folder
2. Camera
3. Video
4. Sounds

I would like to redirect the browse to the image folder of the mobile device like Facebook does.

Is it possible? Thank you!

EDIT 1:

putting accept="image/*" changed from (image/png,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/gif) changed a little bit the situation avoiding choosing audio and video.

Now on Android 5.02 this is what i see:
[image: screenshot]

while on Android 4.42 i see this:

[image: screenshot2]

What i want is getting the same choiches as android 4.4.2 in every device (IOS too).

Or if is possible doing like facebook wich goes straight to the images global folder.

It Seems to be a Android 5 Bug,anyone can help me?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SBO_it/74c7xesb/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your "accept" value is wrong. Try to use "image/*":

```
<input type="file" id="mfile" name="file" class="input display-none optional_check" accept="image/*"/>
```

Now it should work.

Comment: I have image/jpeg set in the real file. This is not what i asked

Comment: Could you provide more information? At my phone this form works exactly like at Facebook.

Comment: Seems like a bug of Android 5. But can you upload your actual HTML to jsfiddle? I'll try it with some devices.

Comment: Couldn't find Android 5 phone, but I tested your code at three Android 4 phones and it works like expected. I suppose that is a bug of Android 5 or may be it's browser. By the way, have you tried another browser?